# Is $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ or $=x$? Isn't $(x^2)^\frac12=x?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, absolute-value, radicals

$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ as [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sqrt%28x%5E2%29&lk=4&num=1) shows. But, as $(x^2)^\frac12=x$, I can't understand where am I wrong interpreting Square-root.

Comment: The square root function gives nonnegative numbers.

Comment: Anyway, the question remains for me: Does this mean $\sqrt x\neq x^\frac12$?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518487/how-is-it-that-sqrtx2-is-not-x-but-x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know that $x^2$ is not an invertible function. To find an inverse you must restrict it. The convention is to restrict the function to positive numbers, hence the $\sqrt y$ function always gives the non negative solution to the equation $x^2=y$.

This being said you understand that the rule:
$$
  (x^p)^q = x^{pq}
$$
is not valid when $x<0$, but is only valid for $x>0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my doubt:)

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$ so if $x\ge 0$ then $\sqrt{x^2}=+x$ and if $x<0$ then $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$. In both cases the square root should be held positive. Many students have troubles in making difference between the question you asked and this fact that $(\pm x)^2=x^2$.

Comment: Does this mean $\sqrt x\neq x^\frac12$?

Comment: @Sush: Nope! these are the same but in different symbolic notations.

Comment: So, why is it incorrect that $(x^2)^\frac12=x^{2\times{\frac12}}=x$?

Comment: Because the statement $(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=x^{2\times\frac{1}{2}}$ is true for only positive numbers $x$.

Comment: @Sush: Think of this $x=(x^2)^{1/2}=((\pm x)^2)^{1/2}=\pm x$. Do u this this is correct? To avoid this event, we define $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: Thank you so much, So should we use the rule $(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=x^{2\times\frac{1}{2}}$ only with positive $x$ as shown by Tigran?

Answer (score 3):

By convention, the square-root sign $\sqrt{}$ denotes the *non-negative* square root. So $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.